# Cannot change legend order in ggsurv() ploot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to specify the legend order in my ggsurv() plot. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(time_to_event = c(2,3,5,7,10),
                 event = c(1,0,1,0,0),
                 grp = factor(c('A','B','A','B','B'),levels=c('A','B')))
                 
fit <- survfit(Surv(time_to_event, event==1) ~ grp, data = df)
ggsurv(fit)
```

[image]

The legend order is different from the factor levels of grp. How can I make the legend order follow the factor levels order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggsurv` orders factor levels in the legend by survival time by default. Use order.legend= FALSE to disable this behaviour.

```
ggsurv(fit,order.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]